# Record Access Control Point BLE explanation - glucose

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, measurement, characteristics

I'm trying to get glucose measurements from glucose meter (Contour One Plus) with Bluetooth LE. I'm able to connect to device. I don't know how to start with Record Access Control Point. I can discover all of characteristics and services. I am asking for an explanation of the theoretical basis.
So, If I'm connected to the device - the first step is to send a request to RACP that I want to read the data? And what happened next? If Response Code Values send value="success" I should look on Glucose Measurement characteristic?

Comment: After connect, you should discover the GATT services. Then set notification for glucose measurement characteristic and indication for the record access control point characteristic. Then write a command to the RACP characteristics. I can also highly recommend to the nRF Connect from Nordic Semiconductor for Android or iOS to discover how your BLE device works.